# Can I use / integrate Einstein chat bot in sales cloud

Tags: servicecloud, sales-cloud, einstein-chatbot

I need to create a chatbot feature in sales cloud. Can I use Einstein chat bot in sales cloud. I know that I might need a service cloud license to create a chatbot but I wanted to know whether I can integrate it anywhere , any cloud.

On searching the web, I only see people using it in service-cloud. Please share ways to create chatbot in sales cloud.

I found this ( this is for any client ) [https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2022/05/introducing-the-einstein-bots-platform-api#:~:text=Einstein%20Bots%20are%20fully%20integrated,in%20the%20Einstein%20Bots%20documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2022/05/introducing-the-einstein-bots-platform-api#:%7E:text=Einstein%20Bots%20are%20fully%20integrated,in%20the%20Einstein%20Bots%20documentation).

Is there any simpler way to create it on sales cloud

Answer (score 0):

You can watch this video for setting up Einstein ChatBots for Cross-Platform:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6N3V_bObT88